# Junit: Need to Mock class partially

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a class like,

```
class AppSave{
@Autowired
AppDaoimpl daoimpl;

@Autowired
AppService appService;

method1(){daoimpl.fewCode()}
method2(){appService.someCode()}
}
```

Written test class like,

```
class AppSaveTest{

@Mock
AppDaoimpl daoimpl;

//What Should I do here So that I can Call someCode() of appService
AppService appService;

@InjectMocks
private AppSave appSave;

test(){
    method2()
}
```

Just for your infomration am using junit1.4.If I mock Appservice then I could execute the impl. in somCode().

Comment: do you want to invoke that as a spring bean or just invoke the methods code?

Comment: you using Spring boot?

Comment: yes spring boot

Comment: I will call like appSave.method2() from my test class

Comment: Can you update your post to actually ask a question ? It's not clear what the issue is at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your test as a @SpringBootTest so that the Spring beans you want to use are available in your test. You can then mark whatever you want mocked as a @MockBean like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class AppSaveTest{

    @MockBean
    AppDaoimpl daoimpl;

    @Autowired
    AppService appService;

    @Autowired
    private AppSave appSave;

    ...
}
```

or if you want to keep using @InjectMocks:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class AppSaveTest{

    @Mock
    AppDaoimpl daoimpl;

    @Autowired
    AppService appService;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private AppSave appSave;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I cannot change prototype now@Plog,Could you please provide some other solution, with @InjecTMocks and one bean mocked whereas other is not..

Comment: What do you mena you cant change prototype?

Comment: Updated answer anyway